# How to get a list of voters per referenda through Polkadot JS?

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, governance

I am trying to assemble a list of all voters on a `referendum` with their votes, etc. I need help on what `storage` pallet to call, I tried calling the functions on the `convictionVoting` pallet which is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some snippets that may help you get started:

```js
const votes = await api.query.convictionVoting.votingFor.entries();
votes.forEach((vote) => {
    if (vote[1].toHuman()['Casting']) {
        if (vote[1].toHuman()['Casting']['votes'].length > 0) {
            console.log(vote[0].toHuman());
            console.log(JSON.stringify(vote[1].toHuman(), null, 4));
        }
    }
});
```

```js
const referenda = await api.query.referenda.referendumInfoFor.entries();
referenda.forEach(async (referendum) => {
    if (referendum[1].toHuman()['Ongoing']) {
        const referendumIndex = referendum[0].args[0].toNumber();
        console.log("Referendum:", referendumIndex);
        console.log(referendum[1].toJSON());
    }
});
```

Resources

- https://polkadot.js.org/docs/kusama/storage#convictionvoting
- https://polkadot.js.org/docs/kusama/storage#referenda